# How do I fix an error when installing scikit-image Python Library?

Tags: python, scikit-image, python-3.10

I am try to install *scikit-image* package in python 3.10 and I use *vscode*. this is my command:
`pip3 install scikit-image`
but I see this error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image  Failed to build scikit-image   
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

vc++ is installed on my windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like scikit-learn is not yet supported on python 3.10. You can downgrade python to [3.9.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-399/) for scikit installation to work fine.